# VIM how to replace "AA" to "BB" in a file

Tags: vim, vi

I need to replace a file which has thousand of lines code.

In the log, it has a specific word which I want to replace this work with some other words.

Say, how to replace all "AA" to "BB" in this file?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use

```
:%s/\<AA\>/BB/g
```

`%` specifies that you want to replace on *all* lines.

`s` tells vim that you want to do a substitution

Between the first `/` and second `/` is what you want to replace (ie `\<AA\>`).

The `\<` and the `\>` are *word boundaries*, making sure that `AA` is matched but `fAA` or `AAg` is not.

Between the second `/` and third `/` is your replacement (ie `BB`)

The final `g` says that you want to replace all occurances on a line (not only the first).

Answer (score 9):

Since you don't know one of the most basic and frequent commands in vi / Vim, the `:substitute` command, and apparently also aren't aware of the great built-in help and many many tutorials on the web (most of which cover the `:s` command), maybe the best approach (if you're using GVIM) is

```
:promptrepl
```

which will bring up a search-and-replace dialog that is very similar to that in other text editors. It's even accessible through the menu *Edit > Find and Replace...*

---

Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll prove a very powerful and efficient editor.