# How to change a word in Vim (and all of its other occurrences)

Tags: vim

I frequently use the combination `c-a-w` to change a word in Vim.

Are there any similar means by which one can quickly also change all other occurrences of said word in the specific file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VIM how to replace "AA" to "BB" in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526475/vim-how-to-replace-aa-to-bb-in-a-file)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+replace+word+file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `gn` option for this purpose, in my case, I have a slightly different version of it

```
" allows me to use a smarter cgn
nnoremap c* *<c-o>cgn
nnoremap c# #<C-o>cgn
```

Now when you have to change a word many times, as long as you have not so many of it, because in this case, a classical substitution would be better, just press `c*` and then press "dot --> ." to change the next occurrencies of it.

If you want to see how awesomeness `gn` can give us have a look at: [Operating on search matches using gn (vimcasts)](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/operating-on-search-matches-using-gn/)

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
%s/<CTRL-R><CTRL-W>/NewWord/g
```

`<CTRL-R><CTRL-W>` means keep control key pressed and hit `R` and `W`.
This copies the word under the cursor to the command line.

See `:help c_CTRL-R_CTRL-W`.

Answer (score 1):

The main command for replacement of all occurrences is `:substitute`. Unfortunately, being an Ex command, it doesn't integrate too well with the single-word replacement (e.g. `caw`) in normal mode: Though you can insert the previously replaced word into the command-line with `<C-R>"`, you still have to enclose it in `\<...\>` to enforce a whole word match, and also escape any special characters inside the word.

That said, there are plugins that offer help in that area. One of them is my [ChangeGlobally plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4321), which offers a `gc{motion}` alternative to `c{motion}` that then applies the change (or deletion) to other matches in the same line or entire buffer. (The plugin page has links to alternative plugins.)

Answer (score 1):

To me the best way is to add a shortcut.

```
nnoremap ge yiw:%s/<C-r>0//g<Left><Left>
```

Now, you can hover a word and press **ge** and start typing the new version of the word then press enter.

To copy the word, we use **yiw**. Then we use the structure **%s/word/newWord/g** to change all occurences. **<C-r>** pastes the yanked into the command line of the vim.  is used for to locate the cursor between the **//**